# Isotope filter from block view to table view

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm not finding anything with my search terms, so I'm hoping this hasn't been asked before: I'm using the Isotope plugin to filter a bunch of items. So far, so good. These items are generally all in a block, like a portfolio. However, the client would *also* like a filter option where it goes from the block layout to a separate list layout, like in the vertical layout mode. But that actually means probably a whole separate div needing to replace the block layout mode, so the vertical layout can be sorted as well. I've tried using the following jQuery to replace the div when clicking the corresponding button, but it's not working.

```
<div class="row main-area">
  <div class="btn-group sort-by-button-group">
     <button class="btn btn-outline-primary active" data-sort-value="original-order">by state</button>
     <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-sort-value="name">by name</button>
     <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-sort-value="size">by size</button>
     <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="listClick">list view</button>
  </div>

  all the grid items here
</div>

<div id="static" class="row" style="display: none;">
  My Static Content
</div>

<div id="list-view" class="row" style="display: none;">
  This is where the new vertical layout and filtering buttons would appear
</div>

<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#listClick').on('click',function(){
        if($('.main-area').css('display')!='none'){
           $('.list-view').html($('#static').html()).show().siblings('.main-area').hide();
        }else if($('.list-view').css('display')!='none'){
           $('.main-area').show().siblings('.list-view').hide();
        }
     });
  });
</script>
```

I'm assuming that there's something about the isotope script that's interfering with trying to bind that button to something else. Any ideas? I'm not a jQuery expert by any stretch, but I'm pretty good at figuring stuff out. Explanations are very very welcome.